# SIM800L: AT+CIICR always goes to PDP DEACT state

Tags: at-command, sim800l

I'm trying to send data to a server using my SIM800L which is connected to a LoPy. Using the attached diagram I want to go from state 0 to 6 in order to send and the issue I encounter is at state 2 ( AR+CIIR that returns an error ).
[SIM800L diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOSUs.jpg)

I know that only **AT+CSTT=“apn”,“pass”**, **AT+CIICR** and **AT+CIFSR** where needed but I’ve used the other commands to show more usefull(?) info.

My output:

```
=========== ATI =============
ATI
SIM800 R14.18

OK

=========== AT+CIPSHUT ===========
AT+CIPSHUT
SHUT OK

=========== AT+CIPSTATUS ===========
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: IP INITIAL

=========== AT+CSTT ===========
AT+CSTT="internet.vodafone.ro","",""
OK

=========== AT+CIPSTATUS ===========
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: IP START

=========== AT+CGATT ===========
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 1

OK

AT+CGATT=1
OK

=========== AT+CGDCONT ===========
AT+CGDCONT= 1,"IP","internet.vodafone.ro","0.0.0.0",0,0
OK

=========== AT+COPS ===========
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"CONNEX GSM"

OK

=========== AT+CREG ===========
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1

OK

AT+CREG=1
OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1

OK

=========== AT+CIPSTATUS ===========
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: IP START

=========== AT+CIICR ===========
AT+CIICR=?
OK

AT+CIICR
+PDP: DEACT

ERROR

=========== AT+CIPSTATUS ===========
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: PDP DEACT

=========== AT+CIFSR ===========
AT+CIFSR
ERROR

=========== AT+CIPSTATUS ===========
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: PDP DEACT
```

I don't know why it does not work to pass to state 3, any help is usefull, thank you !

Comment: What is the response to the command `AT+CGREG?` ? Furthermore: could you please repeat your sequence enabling verbose errors (by means of `AT+CMEE=2`)?

Answer (score 2):

I also used a Vodafone card and in my case the problem was that the TinyGSM libraries are used for the APN data in the gprsConnectImpl routine for the IP.

In the `TinyGsmClientSIM800.h` you can find the line

```
sendAT(GF("+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\""), apn, '"');
```

But Vodafone needs an IP here, so I changed the line as follows for testing purposes:

```
sendAT(GF("+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\""), "139.007.029.017", '"');
```

The information about this can be found here: [Klick me](https://www.vodafone.de/hilfe/mobiles-telefonieren/mobilfunk-services-einrichten.html#so-lauten-die-einstellungen-fuer-vodafone-live).
For APN I use `web.vodafone.de`, username and password are "";.
Since then the connection to the WEB.

Comment: had similar issue with vodafone sim, setting IP to generic value of "0.0.0.0" resolved the problem.